# Bootstrap alert not hiding after shown once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I have a problem with alert messages that I'm showing with jQuery.  Once it is shown, I do data validation and then try to hide it again.

It's not working and there is no error in the console, even log prints before and after it.

**CODE**

```js
$('#password, #confirm_password').on('keyup', function () {
  if ($('#password').val() == $('#confirm_password').val()) {
      $('#error-message').hide();
      $('#message').html('').css('color', 'green');
  } else 
      $('#message').html('Passwords Do Not Match').css('color', 'red');
      $('#error-message').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alert alert-danger" id="error-message">
   <h6 align="left" id='message'></h6> 
</div>
```

It's shown but not hiding again

Comment: Look at the actual css applied in something like Chrome inspector. Better yet, use the dedicated bootstrap way to show/hide alerts. It should be in the docs I’m sure

Comment: It's not applying css, Secondly I tried css but it's not working

Comment: `if else` statement working fine?

Comment: I can not produce this error from above code. Try to create new file(.HTML ) and past above code only. Are you able to produce this error in newly created file? Additionally, Add your code into "code snippet" if possible.

Comment: @Ikram Khan Niazi  Try with `fadeIn(); fadeOut();`

Comment: Try to add curly braces after else { .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing { } on your else statement.

```js
$('#password, #confirm_password').on('keyup', function () {
  if ($('#password').val() == $('#confirm_password').val()) {
      $('#error-message').hide();
      $('#message').html('').css('color', 'green');
  } else {
      $('#message').html('Passwords Do Not Match').css('color', 'red');
      $('#error-message').show();
  }
});
```

```css
.alert {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alert alert-danger" id="error-message">
   <h6 align="left" id='message'></h6> 
</div>

<input type="text" id="password"/>
<input type="text" id="confirm_password"/>
```

Comment: Thanks alot You save my night because my day is already wasted in it :)